# Web API e Owin OAuth - redirecionar para outro domínio (redirect_uri)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

Boa tarde, eu estou tendo um problema para implementar login externo em um projeto no qual eu estou trabalhando.

> ASP.NET Web API + Owin + OAuth.

**Ambiente:** 
Trabalho com dois servidores Server1 e Server2.

**Server1:** Servidor publicado na WEB. Ele abriga arquivos (HTML, CSS, JS). Alem disso, ele funciona como um proxy. Todas as chamadas recebidas (que não são chamadas de arquivos) são redirecionadas para o Server2.

**Server2:** Servidor não publicado. Recebe chamadas apenas no Server1. Esse servidor abriga um WEB API e é nele que o usuário deve ser autenticado.

**Problema:** 
Ao efetuar o login no Server2, o Owin retorna como redirect_uri o seguinte parâmetro:

```
&redirect_uri=http://server2/signin-google
```

Sendo que o parâmetro que eu preciso retornar seria:

```
&redirect_uri=http://server1/signin-google
```

A única configuração que eu encontrei foi a CallbackPath:

```
googleAuthOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions() {
    ClientId = "xxxxxxx",
    ClientSecret = "xxxxxxx",
    CallbackPath = new PathString("/path"),    
    Provider = new GoogleAuthProvider()
};
```

Mas essa configuração não funciona uma vez que new `PathString("http://server1/signin-google")` não é um valor válido.

Alguém sabe como eu soluciono esse problema?

Answer (score 1):

Tive uma dificuldade com Web API e Owin OAuth, segue abaixo a estrutura e como resolvi, talvez possa lhe ajudar.

1) Tenho um web site em asp.net mvc que faz login via identity e Owin OAuth normalmente: facebook e google;

2) Possuo um asp.net web api para servir 3 apps (android, ios e windows phone);

3) Os apps  precisam de autenticação via identity ou social (facebook ou google) para terem acesso ao web api;

Inicialmente tentei fazer com que o web api pudesse fornecer as opções de autenticação social aos apps e tive algumas dificuldades, desisti pois tinha urgência na implementação. Dai resolvi fazer requisição, confirmação e recebimento do token via web OAuth, em caso de social login. Com o token faço o registro no identity e passo a tê-los autenticados no identity normalmente.